# Add multi crawled properties to manage property in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, managed-property, crawled-property

I add 3 crawled properties to a single manage property in SharePoint 2013, I want search information from 3 columns: Office Address, Office Title and Office Mail.

For exemple, I have 3 offices, one has a Title "Office Paris", one has Address "XXXX Paris" and one has mail "Paris@company.fr". I want to search these 3 office with the keyword "Paris".

But when I test this manage property, the office which has a Title "Office Paris" cannot display in search result. it means that manage property works with Address and Mail, it does not work with Title. How can I correct this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that Title is the right managed property?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Ah, I forget this, I will check it. Thank you !